# How can I insert two figures in a row in a LaTex doc.?

Tags: graphics

I)I want to insert two plots done in maple to a LaTex doc.in a row.

II) I want to insert a figure into a LaTex doc.with some text left hand of the fig. Please guide.

Comment: Two `minipage`'s with `0.5\textwidth`?

Comment: The figure can be a  maple plot.

Comment: For I) there are several solutions, depending on whether you want a caption or not: the `subcaption, floatrow` can do that. You can also use minipages or tabular environments. For II) you can use `wrapfig` or `insbox`,  and several others.

Comment: Is it possible to write the commands . I do not need captions.

Comment: @M.R.Yegan You have an answer to this question. Does it help? If so, can you accept it? If not, can you add a comment, why it does not, and can you make your question more clear?

Answer (score 2):

Question I) If you do not need separate captions, simply place both images in one figure.

Question II) Getting an image and text side by side is a bit more complicated, but luckily there are packages like `wrapfig` which do the trick. To learn how this works, have a look at the documentation http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/wrapfig/wrapfig-doc.pdf

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

% just to make this example:
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}

    \section{Two Pictures}

    \begin{figure}[h]
        \includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \hfill
        \includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    \end{figure}

    \section{Text besides Figure}

    \lipsum[1]

    \begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0cm}
        \includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image}
    \end{wrapfigure}

    \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]